# implementing the maclaurin series but getting an incorrect answer

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, taylor-series

I'm trying to implement the Mauriac series for only the first 7 functions in the series. I have an array the contains all the values of (0) up to 5 derivatives. but to simply my objective, I need to do this mathematical function:

f(x)=2+0-13x^2+26*x^3+(-299/12)*(x^4)+13*x^5

so if: f(2)= 175.3

but instead, the code gives me f(2)= 275.0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x,i;

    double term [5] = {2,0,-13,26,-299,13};
    double answer;

    printf("\n\nEnter the value of x in the series :  ");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    term [2]*=(x*x);
    term [3]*=(x*x*x);
    term [4]*=(x*x*x*x)/12;
    term [5]*=(x*x*x*x*x);

    for (i=1; i <6; i++)
    {
        answer = answer + term[i];
    }

    printf("f(%d)= %lf",x,answer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double term [5]` means you can store only `5` `double` values into it but you are storing `6` values which causes undefined behavior. Make it `term [6]`.

Comment: Variable `answer` is being used uninitialized.

Comment: Complementing Achal's comment, indexes in C starts at 0. So if you declared `double term[5]`, it is an array with 5 elements, accessed `term[0]` through `term[4]`.

Comment: This isn't going to bode well either: `(x*x*x*x)/12` can easily integer-div truncate. Ex: `x=2`, then `16/12 = 1` with integer division, not the 1.333~ you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues here. You don't seem to fully understand how arrays work in C. Declaring `term[5]` is an array of 5 elements. The first index of this array is `term[0]`, since arrays always start at 0. It then proceeds like this.

- `term[0]`
- `term[1]`
- `term[2]`
- `term[3]`
- `term[4]`

What you're doing when you're declaring the `term` array, is you are attempting to put 6 values into an array with 5 indexes. This doesn't work, so you'll have to do `term[6]` to create 6 indexes, with the actual index of 6 being out-of-bounds. Another thing I noticed is that you're manually doing exponents (`(x*x*x)` and so on) when you're calculating each element of your array. You should really use the [**`pow()`** function from `math.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/). This function is from the C Math library. To compile a program that includes the C Math library, you must specify it to the linker.

Instead of compiling like this,

```
$ cc program.c -o program
```

You would compile like this, to include the Math library. Note the **-lm**.

```
$ cc program.c -lm -o program
```

I've reconstructed your program to use the `pow()` function. I've also made `x` a double, since we're giving it to pow(), and changed the `%d` in the printf and scanf statements to the proper `%f`. I also gave `answer` an initial value of 0, since you were using the variable uninitialized, as others pointed out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    double x;
    int i;

    double term[6] = {2,0,-13,26,-299,13};
    double answer = 0;

    printf("\n\nEnter the value of x in the series :  ");
    scanf("%f",&x);

    term[2] *= pow(x, 2);
    term[3] *= pow(x, 3);
    term[4] *= pow(x, 4)/12;
    term[5] *= pow(x, 5);

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        answer = answer + term[i];
    }

    printf("f(%f) = %f \n", x, answer);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tested this, and inputting the number 2 at the prompt yields the correct: `f(2.00000) = 175.33333`.

Comment: The correct `printf` and `scanf` format specifier for a `double` is `%f`, not `%lf`.

Comment: Very useful answer to original question.  I took the liberty to add a more compact version to reduce the number of times x is multiplied in the series.  Also `scanf` format specifier for a double is `%lf` not `%f` but `printf` `%f` means `double`.  I guess the edits won't be visible until accepted by peer review.

Answer (score 0):

A different version of the main function would be:

```
  int main(void) {
    double x;
    int i;

    double term[6] = {2,0,-13,26,-299.0/12.0,13};
    double answer = 0;
    double p = 1;

    printf("\n\nEnter the value of x in the series :  ");
    scanf("%lf",&x);

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++, p*=x) {
        answer = answer + term[i] * p;
    }

    printf("f(%f) = %f \n", x, answer);
    return 0;
  }
```

It removes redundant multiplications of `x` and makes the use of term consistent.  Depending upon your application this could be adapted to a function that takes the number of terms, an array of terms, and the value of x, and return the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OP's goal is to evaluate a fifth degree polynomial

> f(x) = 2 - 13x<sup>2</sup> + 26x<sup>3</sup> - (299/12)x<sup>4</sup> + 13x<sup>5</sup>

But the posted code have some issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x,i;  // <- 'x' is declared as 'int'

    double term [5] = {2,0,-13,26,-299,13};  // <- this array has 6 elements, not 5
    double answer;
    // ...
    term [2]*=(x*x);
    term [3]*=(x*x*x);       //    Both 'x' and 12 are 'int', so an integer division
    term [4]*=(x*x*x*x)/12;  // <- is performed: 16/12 = 1 not 1.3333
    term [5]*=(x*x*x*x*x);   //    This is also inefficient

    for (i=1; i <6; i++)     // <- Given 'double term[5]', array indeces should be in [0, 5)
    {
        answer = answer + term[i];
    }
    // ...
}
```

A more efficient way to evaluate a polynomial is the [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method), which *"allows evaluation of a polynomial of degree n with only n − 1 multiplications and n − 1 additions"*.

OP's polynomial could be written as

> f(x) = 2 + x(0 + x(-13 + x(26 + x(-299/12 + 13x))))

The following is an example of such an implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

// Uses Horner's method to evaluate a polynomial
double evaluate_poly(double x, size_t n, double *coeffs)
{
    assert(n  &&  coeffs);
    double y = coeffs[--n];
    while (n)
    {
        y = coeffs[--n] + x * y;
    }
    return y;
}

int main(void)
{
    double terms[] = {
        2.0 , 0.0, -13.0, 26.0, -299.0/12.0, 13.0
    };
    size_t n_terms = sizeof terms / sizeof *terms;

    puts("  x         f(x)\n-----------------");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        double x = i / 5.0;
        double answer = evaluate_poly(x, n_terms, terms);
        printf("%4.1lf   %10.6lf\n", x, answer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Testable [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eiCJkm9GKcjftb0j).